# Java HTTP sample code hangs

Tags: java

I create a simple SWT app with a single button. When the button is clicked, the following code gets executed but it just hangs. I know the URL is ok! Any idea of what could be causing this?

```
HttpGet httpGetRequest = new HttpGet(URL_UUID);

// Execute HTTP request
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGetRequest);

System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
System.out.println(httpResponse.getStatusLine());
System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try set  [timeouts](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html). Otherwise you can use [http-request](https://github.com/jsunsoftware/http-request) built on apache http api.

**Example**

```
static HttpRequest<?> httpRequest = HttpRequestBuilder.createGet(URL_UUID).build();

ResponseHandler<?> responseHandler = httpRequest.execute();
System.out.println(responseHandler.getStatusCode);
```

Comment: How do I user http-request?

Comment: Add dependency into pom.xml or build.gradle [MVNRepository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jsunsoft.http/http-request/0.0.5)

Comment: Hangs on HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();

Comment: Note: Http-request doesn't support default http client  will be added on 1.0.0 version.